# Can I set css of Child in Styled Componet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

In normal CSS, I can apply css to child using reference of parent.

```
.ABC > div {
    color: red;
}
```

I was wondering, can I do same thing in styled component?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: USE `& > div { color: red; }` in your styled component

Comment: For further reading: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. `&` refers to the current element, so you can apply selectors like below:

```
& > div {
    color: red;
}
```

See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zw5y3mzp64) for a demo.

You can see how it applies the style via the chrome debugger:

[image]